# How do I know what service is running on a particular port in linux?

Tags: command-line, networking, process, ip, netstat

I am trying to run weblogic server on my linux machine and I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

I think that the error means that the debugger port which by default is 8453 is already held by some other service . How can I find out what service is runnning in a partcular port number ?

P.S: I used `netstat` command but that shows all the services occupying all ports ..here I am interested in a particular port only.

Comment: And you don't want to use `grep` because of?

Comment: @scai I am new to Linux world. I can ofcourse use the grep command but wanted to find out if there could be a easier way than doing a grep on the output of netstat

Answer (score 85):

Two ways:

- `lsof -i :port -S`
- `netstat -a | grep port`

You can do [`man lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) or [`man netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) for the needed info.
Replace `port` by the port number you want to search for.

Comment: You may want to make that `netstat -a | grep portnumber`. Otherwise you will be at the mercy of /etc/services.

Comment: lsof seems to be the most used :)

Comment: I found that for port 80 I needed higher privileges to see the listing: `sudo lsof -i :80 -S`.
I would guess this is true for any restricted-use port (those at or below 1024 if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped. First when I tried this command on my CentOS, I got the error as `Command Not Found`. Hence I installed them and used the command. For those who are facing the same issue. For Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install lsof` - Installs lsof. If you want to install netstat, then the command is `sudo apt-get install netstat`.  For CentOS: `sudo yum install lsof` and for netstat installation `sudo yum install netstat`.   Note: Usually Ubuntu comes by default installed with these packages.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `fuser` or `lsof` i.e:

```
fuser 8453/tcp
lsof -i TCP:8453
```

If you want more information from `fuser` you can also use the `-v` flag, i.e: `fuser -v 8453/tcp`

Comment: I ca not issue either command . I can see the man pages but when I issued the command I get a "lsof: Command not found.". Similar case with fuser also .

Comment: @Geek you may have to either install the packages or specify the full path depending on your setup.

Comment: I have no option of installing anything on this machine . Which full path are you talking about ? How can I see it ? Can you please put that information in the answer itself ?

Comment: At least lsof is commonly only easily available to the system administrator, by virtue of being placed in one of the `sbin` directories. Try `sudo -i` followed by the `lsof` command, and see if that works better.

Comment: Neither lsof nor fuser are installed by default in Fedora.

Comment: To Install the **lsof**, issue the command as `sudo apt-get install lsof` [Ubuntu]. If you are on CentOS or Redhat then issue the command as `sudo yum install lsof`

Answer (score 11):

for what its worth... depending on the version of `netstat` (specifically GNU `netstat`) you have, you can use

```
netstat -punta | grep <port>
```

this will show you connections in ESTABLISHED and LISTEN states UDP and TCP and it will ignore the UNIX local sockets.  the end result is a nice, neat, small result set.

the `-p` flag will give you the process ID and the process name of whatever is using that port

the `-u` flag shows udp

the `-n` flag is for numerical addresses

the `-t` flag shows tcp

the `-a` shows listening and non-listening sockets

EDIT - The `ss` command has replaced `netstat` in modern EL distros

Answer (score 3):

On centos

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -i tcp:8453 (lsof -i protocol:port)
```

On ubuntu

```
/usr/bin/lsof -i tcp:8453
```

Or, narrow results of netstat using filters.